# MySQL before insert trigger that drops insert if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, database-trigger, unique-constraint

I have the following tables:

slds:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    id     | sld_name  |  
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |  google   |  
+-----------+-----------+
|     2     |  github   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

paths:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
|    id     | path_name  |  sld_id  |   
+-----------+------------+----------+
|    101    |  /cats/    |    1     |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|    102    |  /dogs/    |    2     |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Note that the `sld_name` is a unique index, and `sld_id` is the foreign key of `slds`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO paths (path_name, sld_id)
VALUES ('/dogs/', 1), ('/dogs/', 2) ... this can be hundreds of rows long
```

When the example above happens, I need a way to remove/prevent the insert of the additional `('/dogs/', 2)` row, since that path already exists where `sld_id=2`, and not prevent the `('/dogs/', 1)` row, since `sld_id=1` doesn't have a `/dogs/` path yet.

To implement this, I tried using this trigger:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger after_insert_paths
after insert on paths 
for each row begin
declare path_check INT;

set path_check := (
    select sld_id 
    from paths 
    where path_name=new.path_name and sld_id=new.sld_id
);
if path_check is not null then 
    set new.path_name = null;
end if;

end $$
delimiter ;
```

All this did was prevent inserts from happening at all.

Is there something specific that is wrong with the trigger? or does this strategy not work in general?

Is there a better approach to this that I'm missing?

Any advice would really be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply create a `UNIQUE` key on `paths(path_name, sld_id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE paths ADD UNIQUE paths_idx(path_name, sld_id);
```

Now when an attempt is made to insert a duplicate, MySQL will raise an error, that you can handle with the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO paths (path_name, sld_id) VALUES ('/dogs/', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sld_id = sld_id;
```

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` is safer than `IGNORE` because it only traps duplicate keys errors, while `IGNORE` basically turns *any* error into a warning (datatype error, `NULL` value in non-nullable column, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you added primary key and foreign key relation to both tables and also added unique  constraint to the table. The remove `ignore`  after the `insert`. 
Then `foreign  key and unique  key`
  relation  will help you to stop adding the dublicates. Hope it will help you. Thank you